# modify laravel 5.1 login to use username instead of email

Tags: laravel, authentication, overriding, registering

This function is responsible of defining the username in laravel 5.1 authentication:

```
public function loginUsername()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
}
```

if I modify it to

```
public function loginUsername()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'username';
    }
```

in the foundation file (and adapt my views and db) will this persist in the event of an update? and if not how do I override it and leave the foundation file alone?
I already made a new controller for registering user and I am calling it in my route instead of the default one, however I am finding difficult to do the same with the postlogin route.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of modifying that in `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, you just have to add a property on your `AuthController`:

`protected $username = 'username';`

Comment: this will recognize the username as default login property instead of `email`

Comment: how can we use both username and email for login?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/log-in-with-username-or-email-in-laravel-5

Comment: @AnshulMishra need to be asked in a different stackoverflow question to be answered :)

Comment: How can I do that in version 5.3?